# SQL Where Clause Maximo IBM

Tags: sql, maximo, clause

I want to create a where clause in Maximo.
We have a clause today where we can see the work order about to breach responded SLA.

But i want the clause to calculate to show work order about to breach responded SLA within 1 hour.
Is that possible?

Clause is as follows:

```
(woclass = 'WORKORDER' or woclass = 'ACTIVITY') 
and historyflag = 0 
and istask = 0 
and workorderid in (select sla.ownerid from slarecords sla where sla.ownertable = 'WORKORDER' and sla.ownerid = workorderid)
and wonum not in (select wos.wonum from wostatus wos where wos.status = 'RESPONDED' and wos.siteid = siteid and wos.wonum = wonum)
and sysdate < targstartdate
and (((targstartdate - reportdate) - (targstartdate - sysdate))/(targstartdate - reportdate)*100)>90
and (siteid in (select defsite from maxuser mu where mu.sdx_siteteam is null and mu.userid =  'ALEXANDER.JEPPSON@SODEXO.COM' )
or (siteid in (select sis.siteid from sdx_integratedsites sis where sis.sdx_property = 'COMMANDCENTER' and sis.sdx_type = (select sdx_siteteam from maxuser mu where mu.userid =  'ALEXANDER.JEPPSON@SODEXO.COM' ))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should change

`and sysdate < targstartdate`

to subtract an hour from the target

`and sysdate < targstartdate - 1/24`

or add an hour to the current time

`and sysdate + 1/24 < targstartdate`